# how to determine who invoked a command-prompt window

Tags: command-prompt

I'm running a really long list of scripts, some of which call other scripts and therefore open and close new command-prompt windows. At the end of the run I expect to only find one main command-prompt window opened (the one where the main script running all the sub scripts was ran), but I'm left with two. I need to find out which of my scripts opens a new command-prompt and doesn't close it, but running them one-by-one manually is not an option.
so the question is: given an open command prompt window, is there a way to determine who called it?

thanks!

Comment: It would help to know that these are Windows or Linux command prompts. But I like @shlomi_Agiv's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before every script, set a specific environment variable that will stay when creating a new shell. then test on the new shell which env is defined

you didn't state your environment, but here's an example:

```
export TEMP_VAR=var1
script1
export TEMP_VAR=var2
script2
```

...

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows.
I'll try your solution, thanks!